# Contacts with items and attributes.. 1 column or many?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm setting up a DB and need some input.
I have a list of contacts and each can have 3-50 items with a few attributes per item. Would it be faster, easier to program and easier to maintain to:

1. Have one table with *contacts* and many *item* columns & *attribute* columns.
2. Have one table with *contacts* and serialized text which contains the *items* and *attributes*.
3. Have a table with *contacts* and a table with *items* and *attributes*.
4. Have a table with *contacts*, a table with *items* and a table with *attributes*.
5. ?????

I'm a noob at this (or any) level of Db design so please treat me like I'm 5.  ;)

tools: mysql, workbench 6.1, PHP, some jQuery and javaScript

My solution as of now:#4-->>

- table:**contacts**:(k)id,name,username,password,etc---
- table:**items**:(fk)contactsId,(k)id uniqueItem_1,uniqueItem_2,,,,uniqueItem_24
- table:**itemAttributes**:(k)id(fk)itemsId,(fk)uniqueItemId,attribute_1,attribute_2
- table:**attribute**:(k)id,(fk)itemAttributeId,attribute

Comment: can you give an example of what the table entries look like?

Comment: Not enough info. Too abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly something like this. You may need one more table if the attribute values can vary by contact-item.

```
Contacts
id, name, etc...

Items
id, name, ...

ItemAttributes
id, item_id, attribute_name, value, etc...

ContactItems
contact_id, item_id
```

Additionally, if there is a small, fixed number of items, it may be better to just create a separate table for each type of item and have columns for the attributes instead of a separate table for item-attributes.

Comment: The attributes will be a rather small list of 10-20, but the items will be unique to each contact.  Will there be a performance issues querying the item list if they are in one table.